# Drools: Error: unable to resolve method using strict-mode: KIE Workbench (6.4) : DRL

Tags: drools, jboss6.x, kie-workbench

I have followed all the steps (just a bit different naming convention for Data objects and rule artifacts) as mentioned in drools documentation for creating the drools project as stated in this [link](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.2.0.CR3/drools-docs/html/wb.Workbench.html#wb.QuickStart)

I am trying to do this project in KIE Drools Workbench, installed on jBoss server v 6.4. Though the rule is very primitive, yet I keep getting error as mentioned below when click on validate button as seen the picture. I tried googling and checked that there are certain options like to unset strict validation to false, however I do not know where to set it, in DRL file. 
[image]

[Error: unable to resolve method using strict-mode: nl.cimt.dummyprjt.Company.country()]
[Near : {... country == "NLD" ....}]

Could anyone kindly help here.

Answer (score 0):

Is class Company written according to JavaBeans conventions? Do you have this in it:

```
private String country;
public String getCountry(){ return country; }
```

Change it, the error will be gone. (This standard case doesn't depend on "strict-mode".)

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't depend on "strict-mode". A re-boot of machine (not sure what changed) did the trick (naive of me to say that here though). However, the change of bean doesn't have any impact on this. It's auto-generated post defining the variables. Thanks a lot.

Could not upvote the answer, as I do not have sufficient points.